# How to provide data isolation/ controlled access over data stored in tables across schemas and databases

Tags: database, security, jpa, distributed

I want to provide controlled access to data which is stored in multiple tables. The access is decided based on certain run-time attributes associated with the user. I am looking for a solution which is extensible, performant as well as highly secured.

ILLUSTRATION:
There is a framework level module which stores authorization/access related data for multiple other modules. Then there are n numbers of modules which manage their own life cycle objects. e.g. module Test1 has 1000 instances which are created and stored in its base table. As framework solution I want to protect access to this data by users hence I created a notion of privileges and stored their mapping to user in my own table. Now to provide controlled access to data, my aim is that a user is shown only the objects to which he/she has access to.

Approaches in my mind:

1. I use oracle database and currently we are using VPD (virtual private database) so here we add a policy on each of the base table of above mentioned modules which firstly evaluates the access of currently logged in user from the privileges given to him and then that data is appended into all the query to each of the base tables of other modules (by default by database itself).
   PROS: very efficient and highly secured solution.
   CONS: Can not work if the base tables and our current table are in two different schema. May be two different schema in the same database instance can be overcome but some of my integrator systems might be in separate databases altogether.
2. Design at java layer:
   We connect to our DB's through JPA data sources. So I can write a thin layer basically a wrapper of sorts over EntityManager and then replicate what VPD does for me that is firstly get the access related data from my tables then use a monitored query on the table of my integrator and then may be cache the data into a caching server(optimization).
   CONS: I want to use it in production system hence want to get it done in the first shot. Want to know any patterns which are already implemented in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your solution are flexible enough to work well in a complex scenario like yours. If you have very simple queries, then yes, you can design something like SQL screener at database or "java" level and then just pass all your queries through.

But this is not flexible. As soon as your queries will start to grow complex, improving this query screener will become tremendously difficult since it is not a part of bussiness logic and cannot know the details of your permission system.

I suggest you implement some access checks in your service layer. Service must know for which user it generates or processes the data. Move query generation logic to repositories and have your services call different repository methods depending on user permissions for example. Or just customize repository calls with parameters depending on user permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, here is what i understood from it.
1) I should not be using a monitored query kind of concept as when the queries will become complex then it will become difficult to manage. I was previously considering to use "AdditionalCriteria" annotation of JPA ( dropped now)

2) You are suggesting that i should create stored procedures into the schema of my integrator to which access related information for the current user will be passed and the procedure will return a FILTERED response.

Comment: I was considering that instead of creating procedures into schema of each of my integrator, i provide them a java library for getting data. In that lib, i fetch the access related data for the current user from my DB, fetch the objects from the integrator's DB. Filter it based upon the access level.
Here the catch is that if i can ensure that all the access to the integrator's DB are through my library only then it looks to be a decent solution though i might have to test it from scale perspective.
Procedures are more secured (but less secured than VPD) so i want to improve it.

Comment: @AashishBhandari Stored procedures are ok for access control from my point of view. Standalone access library is also ok, I think. Just ensure that only your library has full access to DB. No client machine should be allowed to talk to DB directly. Only via your library.